# Perl: Directory Copy Using Windows

Tags: perl, file, directory, copy

So I'm trying to write a script to copy a directory and all sub directories and files to another directory (using windows).

I know there are unreliable dependencies involved in this program (such as E: drive being available).

My script seems massively simple compared to some of the other examples I have come across (I don't know if it will copy all sub files and directories).

I am new to Perl and if this sort of thing is above a beginners ability then please don't hesitate to tell me.

**My Script:**

```
use 5.16.3;
use strict;

my $datestring = localtime();

my $orig="C:/Users/Simon/My Documents";
my $new="E:/Back Up/2014/$datestring";
use File::Copy::Recursive::dircopy $orig, $new or die "Copy failed: $!";
```

The actual problem I am sure of this:

*syntax error at line 8, near "$new or"*

Looking for

1. an answer
2. a resource to help me figure it out

Thanks

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~dmuey/File-Copy-Recursive-0.38/Recursive.pm#SYNOPSIS

Comment: @mpapec thanks, in this line `dircopy($orig,$new[,$buf]) or die $!;` what does the `[,$buf]` do, and how do I use it?

Comment: My guess is a parameter for second copy of `$orig` so just skip it.

Comment: `use` is the word to load the module, not to use a function in the module.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little error with needing to `use` the module first:

```
use 5.16.3;
use strict;
use warnings;

# import the sub dircopy into your script
use File::Copy::Recursive qw(dircopy);

my $datestring = localtime();

my $orig = "C:/Users/Simon/My Documents";
my $new  = "E:/Back Up/2014/$datestring";

dircopy($orig, $new) or die "Copy failed: $!";
```

Comment: @i alarmed alien thanks, syntax error gone, but I now get my copy failed message saying "invalid argument at line 11" (last line).

Comment: also really sorry, probably should have mentioned I am using Windows

Comment: @user3001499 you may need to escape the space, or add double quotes to the string that is passed in to `dircopy`. `my $new = qq["E:/Back Up/2014/$datestring"]`

Comment: @BradGilbert double quotes for the string passed to dircopy was it! thanks. post as answer and I can mark as answered

Comment: @user3001499 I think that is a bug in [File::Copy::Recursive](http://p3rl.org/File::Copy::Recursive).